# Logstash: splitted output

Tags: logging, logstash

Is it possible to split output in the Logstash configuration?
for example:
I have input: logs: file1.log and file2.log
wanted output:

1. redis-- easy to configure using docs..
2. %MyBigStorage%\archive\file1.log for    file1.log content only
3. %MyBigStorage%\archive\file2.log for   file2.log content only

and 1 more thing:
is it possible configure it for folders?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can split the output. Also, you can split the output by folder.

First, when you input the logs, you can define the type for each input.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/path/to/first/folder/*"  # The * is tell logstash input all the log file in this directory
        type => "file1.log"
    }
    file {
        path => "/path/to/second/folder/*"  
        type => "file2.log"
    }
}

output {
    if [type] == "file1.log" {
         # output to XXX
    } else if [type] == "file2.log" {
         # output to YYY
    }
}
```

Hope this can help  you.

Comment: no ) I dont want to write file name in the "output" section

Comment: You no need to write file. In the output section you can use all the output api provided by Logstash. In my answer i just say that is only an example. Or you can provide more information about what you want!